# Unable to get single object GET data

Tags: python, rest, django-rest-framework

I am getting single entry data through `127.0.0.8000/item/<id>`.
I get the following errors in console

```
File "C:\Users\Ahmed\djangowallet\wallet\views.py", line 16, in getSingleData queryset = Wallet.objects.all(id=pk) TypeError: BaseManager.all() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'
```

**This is my Views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getData(request):
    queryset = Wallet.objects.all()
    serializer = WalletSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request': request})
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def getSingleData(request,pk):
    queryset = Wallet.objects.all(id=pk)
    serializer = WalletSerializer(queryset, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['POST'])
def postData(request):
    serializer = WalletSerializer(data = request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
```

**My URLS.py is following**

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.getData),
    path('item/<str:pk>/', views.getSingleData, name="item"),
    path('create/', views.postData, name="create"),
]
```

Comment: don't know django... Maybe you can .filter(id=pk) instead of "all"

Comment: Change `Wallet.objects.all(id=pk)` to `Wallet.objects.get(id=pk)`